# Careers invitation reminder email isn't very good at remembering

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, invitation

The other day I needed to take a screenshot of the Careers invitation interface, so I sent myself an invite at an alternate email address. Today I received a reminder that I had (obviously) not accepted the invitation yet, which reads:

> We noticed you have not accepted our invitation to join Stack Overflow
>   Careers. Only 3 days remain before it expires, and we’d love to have
>   you. In case you missed the invitation, or never got it, **here it is
>   again**:
>
> --
>
> In recognition of your contributions to Stack Overflow, we’d like to
>   invite you to create a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers
>   2.0.
>
> A Careers 2.0 profile is a great place to showcase your professional
>   work as a programmer – Stack Exchange answers, open source projects,
>   even the books you’ve read.
>
> ...
>
> Even if you decide not to join Careers 2.0, we would like to thank you for all your contributions to Stack Overflow. It wouldn’t be the same without you.

(emphasis mine)

The problem is that the above text (and the subject line) are specific to the Careers-initiated invitations – The user-initiated invitations, which is what I originally received, start off like this:

> Tim Stone has invited you to post your profile on Stack Overflow
>   Careers 2.0.
>
> Careers 2.0 is a great place to build a showcase of your professional
>   work as a programmer. It is open by invitation only.
>
> ...

Since (as far as I know) there's no guarantee that the email recipient is actually a Stack Overflow user in the case where an invite was sent to them by a Careers user, the reminder email should probably make sure to use the appropriate invitation text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good find. This will be fixed for future invitations.